# problems with async threads (using pthread). sorry, but more specific in body

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

url of code: http://pastebin.com/d62UWUtc

there is almost 320 lines. with comments, that explain each function and variable. please look through it first.

now, if you try to compile, then you notice, that first 1-2 minutes directory, which specified as "path" is empty, because every file for thread that is created is being deleted almost immediately.
but if you wait for 2-3 minutes, you can see, that the function, that removes files just getting to late and not deleting some files. you can see the same thing from program's log too.

question is: can i make program such way, that it delete ANY file, that was created, after proper examining the file?

Comment: also, my problem is that clean-up function just doesn't have enough time for deleting files or there is a bug in the algorithm?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is simple : just synchronize your threads (barriers, locks ... whatever you want) so your cleanup thread can wait for resources to be freed.

But seriously : why do you use files in this situation ? anything that involves small "temporary files" is in itself dubious, especially in a threaded application. If you really have to use them, at least, use tmpfile(). but from what i see from the source, you simply doesn't need them. You could easily replace them with thread-safe shared memory.

Comment: em.. the point is, that threads must run async and somehow notify that they finished. also, i need returned value of function, that was running in thread.

Comment: from the man page of tmpfile: The file will be automatically deleted when it is closed... So, when function opens tmpfile, and write there it's data, it will be deleted on close, yeah? but, i need to check content of the file. so, function, that opened file must somehow pass the descriptor of file etc... really, in that case, i don't see what will be the difference? Do function that cleans up tmp files have enough time for removing files?

Comment: Your threads can perfectly notify that they have finished without using any files. They can use their return value for example.

Comment: but how can i get their return value without joining, which means without syncing them?

Comment: Your program already require synchronization. Threads that aren't joined nor detached are waiting for the program to terminate. Your malloc/realloc/free call have a mutex inside. And don't get me started on files : they uses LOADS OF MUTEXES internally, (and are slow btw). Your threads are already synchronized. Live with it. synchronization-free programs are very hard to write and easy to break, and they don't offer much better performance. Just trash your "synchronization free" idea, and rewrite your program with proper synchronization.

Comment: look, i just cannot understand: if i join threads, then, if one of threads work for about an hour, for example, then main program should wait an hour to continue it's work, right? the point is that i need main program working and not waiting each thread to complete it's work. also, i didn't understand what is detaching thread for and how can i use it here.

Comment: in any ways: i need the "action" thread working detached AND i need the value it returns. so, how can i implement it if not with files?